# how to draw only axis on plot, not rectangle

Tags: r, plot

Sorry I cannot find this: when I draw any plot in R, I have arrround graph area rectangle. Its left side is X axis and bottom line is Y axis, which I want to have. But there are always also lines on the right side and on the top of graph area and these I do not want. How to suppress that two lines? I want only two lines - axis, not rectangle. Thanks
(that rectangle which I mean includes axis)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See ?par, option bty

```
par(bty="l")
```

EDITED: An example:

```
plot(1:4)
par(bty="l")
plot(1:4)
```

Comment: I add it, but it do not change anything. But smu's answer help me

Comment: yes - this is it! Thank you. Previously I set bty in plot command itself and that was probably wrong. This way it works also on my computer, thanks for your patience

Comment: @gutompf: If you think this answer is what your are looking for, please vote up and set it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

you want `frame.plot = FALSE`

```
plot(1,1, frame.plot=F)
```

Comment: Best answer! Worked like a charm for me, and avoid changing the "par" using par(bty="1")